# Can you open multiple Chrome extension pages which use chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a strange situation where one content page seems to nuke background script communication for all the others.

It's strange, as I can see the calls come through to the background script in DevTools, but as soon as I open copies of the main content page **chrome-extensions://xxx/index.html** all the other pages which expect a result from chrome.runtime.sendMessage don't get one.

I'm not sure if it has something to do with the warnings here:

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple

> Note: If multiple pages are listening for onMessage  events, only the
>   first to call sendResponse() for a  particular event will succeed in
>   sending the response. All other responses to that event will be
>   ignored.

To be honest, I find that text a little ambiguous in my case. I think it means in the handler, that `sendResponse()` can only be called once, but that's not what's happening here, as the content `sendMessage()` is a separate page / process.

Then again, it states "multiple pages" so does that mean only one page at a time can use `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener()` ?

I'm stumped.

If I close any of the main content pages (the ones with the most complex build) and leave open some of the much simpler content pages (which only make one call to the background script on load) the simpler content pages (without the listeners) all work.

As soon as I open the main content page (with the listener) the simpler pages don't work any more, and if I open two of the main content page, neither of the pages (with the listeners) work.

My message sending is wrapped in a helper library I'm using to serialize and handle errors from passed messages and additionally I'm using the Web Extensions Polyfill to provide me with a nicer promise-based API, but it's been working with everything I've thrown at it in the past two months and this app is complex.

I'm using the one-time send-message format:

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage(id || null, payload).then( ... )
```

Next step is to look at the long-lived connection.

I'm sure this must be a problem others have encountered.

Has anyone had anything similar?

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: It's possible to have many listeners, but only one can respond to your sendMessage as noted in the documentation so maybe the browser closes the connection as soon as one of the listeners actually responds. You can test it by commenting out the sendResponse part inside the listener or whatever substitute you're using for it. In case of success, long-lived messaging may be the right choice here indeed. Or there might be a bug in that library you're using. I assume it's not in Mozilla's WebExtension pollyfill? If so, consider testing without it.

Comment: Yeah, good advice about testing without it - that is certainly one of the steps I will use to debug - reduce the problem down to its essence. I'll feed back if / when I find the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this with the same or similar problem, I eventually got to the bottom of it, and the answer is that the first listener to respond wins the race, and all subsequent listeners are ignored.

Writing a robust cross-process messaging solution is actually pretty complex, with various error and edge cases to consider, so as of 2023 I revisited my code, re-wrote it, and extracted it into a standalone library:

- https://github.com/davestewart/extension-bus

It solves almost every messaging use case, is MV2 and MV3 compatible, is **extremely** well-documented, and the [code](https://github.com/davestewart/extension-bus/blob/main/src/index.ts) is **liberally**-commented (should you wish to understand what is going on under the hood).

Hopefully it can make your extension messaging much, much easier.